# Error while trying to insert Model with List of another Model in ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, ajax

I have a PatientModel that has some attibutes and one of them is a List of ContactModel. I made it that way so one patient can have more than one contact store to his data. I'm using a PartialPage to add input fields whenever the user want to add more contacts.

This here is the PartialView for the divs

```
@model Vital365.Models.ContactModel
<div class="d-flex mb-2">
    <div class="me-2">
        <label for="Ddd">DDD</label>
        <input id="dddInput" class="form-control" asp-for="Ddd" name="Ddd">
        <span asp-validation-for="Ddd" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="me-2">
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Número</label>
        <input id="phoneNumberInput" class="form-control" asp-for="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber">
        <span asp-validation-for="PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ContactName">Nome</label>
        <input id="contactNameInput" class="form-control" asp-for="ContactName" name="ContactName">
        <span asp-validation-for="ContactName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Create view for the Patient

```
@model Vital365.Models.PatientModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Adicionar paciente";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-6 font-weight-bold text-primary">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    <br />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form id="insereCliente" asp-controller="Patient" asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <!-- Informações do Paciente -->
        <div class="card shadow border-primary mb-3">
            <div class="card-header text-light bg-primary">
                <h4 class="card-title">Informações do Paciente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="name">Nome</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" asp-for="Name" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o nome...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="lastName">Sobrenome</label>
                    <input id="lastName" type="text" asp-for="LastName" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o sobrenome...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="gender">Gênero</label>
                    <select id="gender" asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" title="Selecione o gênero">
                        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Selecione o gênero</option>
                        @foreach (var gender in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PatientGender)))
                        {
                            <option value="@gender">@gender</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                    <input id="cpfData" type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" asp-for="Cpf" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o CPF...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Cpf" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="rg">RG</label>
                    <input id="rg" type="number" asp-for="Rg" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o RG...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Rg" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    <input type="email" asp-for="Email" class="form-control mb-2" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Digite o e-mail...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="birthDate">Data de nascimento</label>
                    <input id="birthDate" type="date" asp-for="BirthDate" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite a data de nascimento...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="BirthDate" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Informações do Telefone -->
        <div class="card shadow border-primary mb-3">
            <div class="card-header text-light bg-primary">
                <h4 class="card-title">Informações do Telefone</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="ContactsFieldClass">
                    <partial name="_ContactsPartial.cshtml" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-2" id="addPhoneContact">Adicionar Contato</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Informações do Endereço -->
        <div class="card shadow border-primary mb-3">
            <div class="card-header text-light bg-primary">
                <h4 class="card-title">Informações do Endereço</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <input id="cepData" pattern="^[0-9]*$" type="text" asp-for="Address.Cep" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o CEP...">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button id="clearCep" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Limpar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="street">Rua</label>
                    <input id="streetData" type="text" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Address.Street" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Rua">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.Street" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="number">Número</label>
                    <input id="number" type="text" asp-for="Address.Number" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o número...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.Number" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="complement">Complemento</label>
                    <input id="complement" type="text" asp-for="Address.Complement" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Digite o complemento...">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.Complement" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="neighborhood">Bairro</label>
                    <input id="neighborhoodData" type="text" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Address.Neighborhood" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Bairro">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.Neighborhood" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
                    <label for="city">Cidade</label>
                    <input id="cityData" type="text" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Address.City" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Cidade">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.City" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="state">Estado</label>
                    <input id="stateData" type="text" readonly="readonly" asp-for="Address.State" class="form-control" placeholder="Estado">
                    <span asp-validation-for="Address.State" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group mt-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="createBtn">Cadastrar</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" asp-controller="Patient" asp-action="Index" role="button">Voltar</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#addPhoneContact', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Patient/DisplayNewContact',
                success: function (partialView) {
                    $('.ContactsFieldClass').append(partialView);
                }
            });
        });

        function getPatient() {
            var patient = {
                name: $('#name').val(),
                lastName: $('#lastName').val(),
                gender: $('#gender').val(),
                cpf: $('#cpfData').val(),
                rg: $('#rg').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                birthDate: $('#birthDate').val(),
                address: {
                    cep: $('#cepData').val(),
                    street: $('#streetData').val(),
                    number: $('#number').val(),
                    complement: $('#complement').val(),
                    neighborhood: $('#neighborhoodData').val(),
                    city: $('#cityData').val(),
                    state: $('#stateData').val()
                }
            };

            return patient;
        }

        function getContacts() {
            var contacts = [];

            const dddInput = document.querySelectorAll('#dddInput');
            const phoneNumberInput = document.querySelectorAll('#phoneNumberInput');
            const contactNameInput = document.querySelectorAll('#contactNameInput');

            for (var i = 0; i < dddInput.length; i++) {
                contacts.push({
                    ddd: dddInput[i].value,
                    phoneNumber: phoneNumberInput[i].value,
                    contactName: contactNameInput[i].value
                });
            }
            return contacts;
        }

        $(document).on('click', '#createBtn', function (e) {
            var pat = getPatient();
            var contacts = getContacts();

            // Adicione os contatos ao objeto do paciente
            pat.PhoneContacts = contacts;
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(pat),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/Patient/Create',
                success: function () {
                    alert('Success!');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And finally here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(PatientModel patient)
{
    try
    {
        patient.Cpf = patient.Cpf.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

        await _patientService.InsertAsync(patient);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return BadRequest("Erro ao processar a solicitação.");
    }
}

public ActionResult DisplayNewContact()
{
    try
    {
        return PartialView("Views/Patient/_ContactsPartial.cshtml");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception for debugging
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The ajax request is sent without a problem, it get the data from the Patient and the Contact and store it in a json. But when I press the button to submit the form, it returns: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ().

I tried to use 'debugger;' on the js script and also a breakpoint while debuging in the controller. The problem is that debugger doesn't show any message for the error and the breakpoints don't even get triggered, making me think this code isn't reaching the controller.

Comment: You have to send a RequestVerificationToken.val()  in your AJAX Post.

Comment: Thank you so much, man! Got stuck in this for a long time and that really was what I was missing. Made some adjustments and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send a RequestVerificationToken.val() in your AJAX Post.

Comment: That's correct. Right after my form started I added-> 
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" /> <- so I can retrieve the token and on the request I did this:

            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

Sent it with my request and it worked like a charm.